# What is wrong with my JavaScript code in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am currently reading a book call Mastering node.js which has an example code i have written below.When i run this node, No error is shown but as well as nothing is getting printed on terminal.

```
let Readable    =   require('stream').Readable;
let fs          =   require('fs');
let readable    =   new Readable;
let count       =   0;

readable._read  =   function(){
    if(++count) {
        return readable.push(null);
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        readable.push(count+"\n");
    }, 2000);
};

readable.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
if(++count) {
    return readable.push(null);
}
```

You initialized `count` to `0`, so the first time `_read` is called, `++count` returns `1`. The function immediately returns (after ending the stream by pushing `null`) and `setTimeout` is never called.

If you change it to e.g. `++count > 10` ([as in the text](https://books.google.com/books?id=fOgtAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT39&lpg=PT39&dq=%22return+readable.push(null);%22&source=bl&ots=_7rKZC65wY&sig=CcJxHVVkncJztbANO9OHHLQmRtc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpq57pn8zSAhXnslQKHUDXC-IQ6AEILDAE#v=onepage&q=%22return%20readable.push(null)%3B%22&f=false)), it will write the numbers `1` to `10` to stdout as expected.